# mysql advance search query with mulitivalued field

Tags: php, mysql

i have a search function to search by different criteria from a db table.
here is the table' field with some data

```
id       first_name       last_name      province_id
1          ali              alii          2,12
2          ahmad            ahmadi        22,1,4
```

a person can be in different province, and its saved in table separating by "," in province field, i know it is not normalized.
i use followed function for search

```
$WHERE_ARR = array();
    if(trim($first_name)!=""){
        $WHERE_ARR['first_name']        = " p.first_name like '%".$first_name."%' ";
    }
    if(trim($last_name)!=""){
        $WHERE_ARR['last_name']     = " p.last_name like '%".$last_name."%' ";
    }

    if(trim($province)!=""){
        $WHERE_ARR['province'] = " p.province_id = ".$province." ";
    }     
    $WHERE_STR  =   implode(' AND ', $WHERE_ARR);
    $WHERE_STR  =   (trim($WHERE_STR)!="")?" AND " . $WHERE_STR:'';

    $QUERY  =   "
                SELECT p.*,pr.province
                FROM ndi_participants p,ndi_provinces pr
                WHERE pr.province_id = p.province_id
                ". $WHERE_STR . " 
                ORDER BY pr.province ASC
                LIMIT ".$start.", " . $perpage . "
                ";
    return $this->db->query($QUERY);
```

for sure it is not exact when i search by province field.
how can i search by province field when it is multivalued separating by ","
note: i am using codeigniter

thanks for your helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `FIND_IN_SET` mysql function to search in provience_id

```
if(trim($province)!=""){
        $WHERE_ARR['province'] = " p.province_id = FIND_IN_SET(".$province.",p.province_id)";
    }
```

Comment: Find_in_set is MySQL function, so need to be without quotes. `" p.province_id = FIND_IN_SET(".$province." ,p.province_id)";`

Comment: A very important thing to notice is that FIND_IN_SET will return the index of the string present,

For example, SELECT FIND_IN_SET('1','4,3,7,21,1'); will return 5 and not 1. So you query should be changed to check for the function return value should be greater than `0` and not the equal to the value you want to check.

Comment: I presume ndi_provinces has one row per province. Hence you will also need to use FIND_IN_SET on the JOIN as well.